# Redux: Shared actions

Tags: redux, react-redux

I have a few actions in my app that need to be shared by a few different react components. For example, I have a `fetchAPIData` action creator which accepts some params and fires off actions to to make a fetch (using a custom fetch middleware i've written):

```
export function fetchAPIData(params) {

  const actions =  
    [
      types.API_CALL, 
      types.RECEIVE_API_DATA,
      types.API_ERROR
    ];

  const params = { 
    method: 'params.method',
    params
  };

  return fetch(actions, params);
};
```

This action and others like this needs to be called by various different parts of the app so i've created a `common-actions` directory where these actions live. This feels like the wrong approach so I am wondering if there is a more accepted way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use `connect` function [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)

You can then import your actions to the top level component, and bind them with the state you want. then pass the props to any children you want. quick example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// Import actions below
import * as myActions from '/redux/actions/myActions';
// Make sure redux, react-redux are installed
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { redux, actions } = this.props; // the redux state.
    const { actionName } = actions;
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => actionName()}> {/* Dispatching redux action... */}
        Dispatch action
      </button>
      <ChildComponent {...this.props} />, {/* Now you can pass the props to any children */}
    </div>;
  }
}

// take any state from redux you want and return it within redux object
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  redux: {
    myState: state.myState,
  },
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators({
    ...myActions,
    // import actions below...
  }, dispatch),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App); // The component name you want to bind the state and the actions to.
```

I left notes so you can understand what's going on. This is ES6.